# How to send an email using JS or JQUERY but no MAILTO

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

Indeed it is an awesome day to everyone but not for me because I've been handling this battle cry for more than 13 days now and cant get it done. I have searched across the web but cant find the solution that can get my butt out of this mess. And yes stackoverflow is always my last resort when things get worse.

Can anyone suggest what is the best way(or even alternative) in sending email using js or jquery ?. Perhaps a simple snippet would do. Thanks!

Comment: You have to send mail from a server. Submit a form or send data to server using ajax. If you don't have a server there are numerous email sending services you can sign up for

Comment: I have a server, I have a domain hosted in hostgator. What should I do ?

Comment: write an endpoint in whatever server side language you are using and submit the data needed to that endpoint and send mail from there.

Comment: look at this sir. This is my predicament before : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543037/send-email-from-a-domian?noredirect=1#comment66400216_39543037

Comment: that has nothing to do with using jQuery as you are asking here

Comment: Also your host should have plenty of information on how to configure sending mail

Comment: yes that's why I said "before" so I jump to jquery or plain js instead

Comment: you need to fix your server side problem first

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send an email within the client browser. If your website is running on your own webserver, you can send a request from within the browser to your server that sends an email. If you're running a node.js server, there are many email apis.

For example, my business is a Mailjet customer, and so I can use the node-mailjet api on my server-side. Also there's https://nodemailer.com/ and similar npm packages.

Answer (score 0):

**Sending email only using javascript on client-side is not possible.** By that you would give full control to user what and where he sends email - cool spam solution..

**I wouldn't recommend to expose service from server that send email to client-side from server-side with full settings of message that will be sent.** You don't want to allow spamming.

Only good approach is to predefine email on server and then **when triggering action occurs resolve dynamic values in email on server and send email from server**. Still you have to ensure user cant spam with some security policy.

**So how to get out of this ?** Implement service on server that will send emails for you (called with AJAX), lets say by code name and parameters. On server-side, choose template by code-name and resolve it by parameters passed with server request. Implement you security policy so you can be sure user cant spam (for example when user can choose to which email address will be message sent). Then pass it all to SMTP.